# How to parse a Uniprot Dat file to retrieve GO in python?

Tags: python, parsing, biopython, bioservices

I have tried BioPython SeqIO and other parsers but couldn't find any good tool to parse DAT files.

```
https://omics.pnl.gov/software/uniprot-dat-file-parser
```

I have tried this one but they don't provide any gene annotations

```
http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO
```

They mostly talk about taking inputs of FASTA and not DAT file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
   for record in SeqIO.parse("Fasta/f002", "fasta"):
...     print("%s %i" % (record.id, len(record)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Those look like what Biopython calls `"swiss"` format, the plain text format used at SwissProt prior to it being called UniProt. Try:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
   for record in SeqIO.parse("example.dat", "swiss"):
       print("%s %i" % (record.id, len(record)))
```

See also the table for formats at http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

Answer (score 0):

Dear Muhammad Zeeshan,

you can use the query functions of the python library `pyuniprot` to get sequence (or many thing else)

- [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUniProt)
- [Read the docs](http://pyuniprot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

install (with pip or git clone) and update. Find out which taxonomy identifier fits to your organisms. Example here (human, mouse, rat). Don't make a full update for all organisms (takes very long).

```
pyuniprot.update(taxids=[9606, 10090, 10116])
```

Use following python code for your problem:

Assuming **1433E_HUMAN** and **A4_HUMAN** are the identifier of interest:

Python code:

```
import pyuniprot
query = pyuniprot.query() 
entries = query.entry(name=('1433E_HUMAN', 'A4_HUMAN'))  
seqs = [x.sequence.sequence for x in entries]
```